# Django Formset - Check if row mark deleted

Tags: python, django

How to check if formset row is mark as deleted?

```
for row in myformset:
    //check if row is mark as deleted
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but if you just want to look at deleted rows/forms, you can use `myformset.deleted_forms`

Comment: yes, this really helps. it returns marked deleted rows. thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#can-delete

> Similar to can_order this adds a new field to each form named DELETE and is a forms.BooleanField.

It's just a django form field called `DELETE` so it should be accessible via `row.cleaned_data.get('DELETE')`